# egg package import error in python project deploy

Tags: python, shell, python-2.7, import, egg

Need to migrate my project to a new server. Both server run on ubuntu 14.04.
There are three python files `A.py`,`B.py`,`C.py` in my project.

- B is imported in A.py
- C is imported in B.py and
- in C.py , `from SOAPpy import Parser,Types,buildSOAP,voidType`  is imprted

I Run "python A.py" to start  whole service.

After installed SOAPpy package, I run python interactive shell and input `import SOAPpy` ,everything is OK. But when i run `python A.py` in ubuntu shell, I got a `ImportError: No module named 'SOAPpy` error.

In fact I got this error in my old ubuntu server. I unzip SOAPpy's zip format egg file into a same name dir to solve it. I also can solve this error by add a line "import SOAPpy" in A.py.

But when deploy this in new ubuntu server. unzip egg file to a same name package can't solve this error and even lead a import error in python interactive shell .

there are 3 question:

1. why import egg package is ok in python interactive shell but get error in linux shell?
2. why a line `import SOAPpy` in A.py can affect `from SOAPpy import Parser,Types,buildSOAP,voidType` in C.py?
3. why old server's  method does not work in my new server?

Comment: Please read tutorial how to install Python packages - you are not supposed to extract egg files by hand: https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/installing.html

Comment: I  installed SOAPpy package with "python setup.py intstall" command line( As of version 0.9.8 SOAPpy can be installed using the standard python package installation tools ). And SOAPpy can be imported in python interactive shell, but fail in my project. But I will use pip to install again. Tks !

Comment: If possible read the part of creating virtualenv for creating package installation environments. Virtualenv solves many headaches.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I use "pip uninstall SOAPpy" to remove the egg package,then use "pip install SOAPpy" to install a new one (not in egg format). Problem solved.